# Mina Deploy Not Working All the Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, mina

I have been having this issue for 3 months or so now. When I do a mina deploy no errors will happen and it shows starting/stopping of sidekiq etc.. but sometimes the latest code doesn't actually deploy to the production server. Using the same code I have never had this issue on the staging environment either, which is really confusing.

To fix the issue, I have to manually kill the unicorn pid and then do a re-deploy and this works every time.

I'm not very familiar with any of this and it is mainly copied from articles & SO, but do you see anything in the code that could be causing issues? Should I be stopping unicorn and then starting it back up instead of just restarting it? My thought there is that I might miss requests.

```
desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do

  # stop accepting new workers
  invoke :'sidekiq:quiet'

  invoke :'git:clone'
  invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
  invoke :'bundle:install'
  invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
  invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
  invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

  to :launch do
    invoke :'sidekiq:restart'
    invoke :'unicorn:restart'
  end
end
```

Is there anyway I can output statements at certain times inside of the deploy or have it create a log?

-- EDIT: (ADDED TRACE) --

This is a passing trace. Is there some type of error that should show up on a failing trace that I can look for? It doesn't fail all the time, but I can run trace each time to try to catch a failing one.

```
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke rbenv:load (first_time)
** Execute rbenv:load
** Execute deploy
** Invoke sidekiq:quiet (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute sidekiq:quiet
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Execute git:clone
** Invoke deploy:link_shared_paths (first_time)
** Execute deploy:link_shared_paths
** Invoke bundle:install (first_time)
** Execute bundle:install
** Invoke rails:db_migrate (first_time)
** Execute rails:db_migrate
** Invoke rails:assets_precompile (first_time)
** Execute rails:assets_precompile
** Invoke deploy:cleanup (first_time)
** Execute deploy:cleanup
** Invoke sidekiq:restart (first_time)
** Execute sidekiq:restart
** Invoke sidekiq:stop (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute sidekiq:stop
** Invoke sidekiq:start (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute sidekiq:start
** Invoke unicorn:restart (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute unicorn:restart

-----> Loading environment
       $ source ~/.bashrc

-----> Loading rbenv
       $ export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv"
       $ export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
       $ eval "$(rbenv init -)"

-----> Creating a temporary build path
       $ touch "deploy.lock"
       $ mkdir -p "$build_path"
       $ cd "$build_path"

-----> Quiet sidekiq (stop accepting new work)
       $ RAILS_ENV="staging" bundle exec sidekiqctl quiet /home/deploy/PATH       $ RAILS_ENV="staging" bundle exec sidekiqctl quiet /home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/pids/sidekiq.pid

-----> Fetching new git commits
       $ (cd "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//scm" && git fetch "git@github.com:k       $ (cd "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//scm" && git fetch "git@github.com:kenmazaika/PATHNAME.git" "master:master" --force)

-----> Using git branch 'master'
       $ git clone "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//scm" . --recursive --branch "       $ git clone "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//scm" . --recursive --branch "master"
       Cloning into '.'...
       done.

-----> Using this git commit

       $ git --no-pager log --format='%aN (%h):%n> %s' -n 1
       MYNAME (a0ba681):
       > Merge pull request #2040 from repo/issue2039
       $ rm -rf .git


-----> Symlinking shared paths
       $ mkdir -p "./config"
       $ mkdir -p "."
       $ rm -rf "./config/database.yml"
       $ ln -s "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/config/database.yml" "./co       $ ln -s "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/config/database.yml" "./config/database.yml"
       $ rm -rf "./log"
       $ ln -s "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/log" "./log"
       $ rm -rf "./config/secrets.yml"
       $ ln -s "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/config/secrets.yml" "./con       $ ln -s "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/config/secrets.yml" "./config/secrets.yml"

-----> Installing gem dependencies using Bundler
       $ mkdir -p "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/bundle"
       $ mkdir -p "./vendor"
       $ ln -s "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/bundle" "./vendor/bundle"
       $ bundle install --without development:test --path "./vendor/bundle" --de       $ bundle install --without development:test --path "./vendor/bundle" --deployment

       ### USING A BUNCH OF GEMS ###

-----> DB migrations unchanged; skipping DB migration

-----> Skipping asset precompilation
       $ cp -R "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//current/public/assets" "./public"

-----> Cleaning up old releases (keeping 5)
       $ cd "/home/deploy/PATHNAME//releases" || exit 15
       $ count=`ls -1d [0-9]* | sort -rn | wc -l`
       $ remove=$((count > 5 ? count - 5 : 0))
       $ ls -1d [0-9]* | sort -rn | tail -n $remove | xargs rm -rf {}

-----> Build finished

-----> Moving build to releases/301
       $ mv "$build_path" "$release_path"

-----> Updating the current symlink
       $ ln -nfs "$release_path" "current"

-----> Launching
       $ cd "$release_path"

-----> Stop sidekiq
       $ RAILS_ENV="staging" bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /home/deploy/PATHl       $ RAILS_ENV="staging" bundle exec sidekiqctl stop /home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/pids/sidekiq.pid 10
       Sidekiq shut down gracefully.

-----> Start sidekiq
       $ nohup bundle exec sidekiq -e staging -C /home/deploy/PATHNAME//current/config/sidekiq.yml -i 0 -P /home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/pids/si       $ nohup bundle exec sidekiq -e staging -C /home/deploy/PATHNAME//current/config/sidekiq.yml -i 0 -P /home/deploy/PATHNAME//shared/pids/sidekiq.pid >> /home/deploy/PATHNAME//current/log/sidekiq.log 2>&1 &

-----> Starting Unicorn...
```

Comment: May you show some trace?

$ mina deploy --trace

Comment: @cnnr I added a trace but it was a passing deploy. Is there anything specific I can look for?

Comment: I've no experience with mina+unicorn (only capistrano+unicorn and mina+puma), but I think that's your problem here:

_To fix the issue, I have to manually kill the unicorn pid and then do a re-deploy and this works every time._

Sometimes I met such problem with unicorn: it didn't have time to finish correctly and process continue rolling up with previous release.

You may try to change `unicorn:restart` task with force stop: kill process (by pid), remove pid file, and after that launch new instance of unicorn.